# How to trigger enter key programmatically in search box of SharePoint 2019 library using jQuery

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, javascript, jquery

I have tried below code:

1. Set the value in search text box

```
jQuery("#inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2_lsinput").val("med");
```

2. Trigger Enter key:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 13 
e.keyCode = 13
jQuery('#inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2_lsinput').focus();
jQuery('#inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2_lsinput').trigger(e);
```

But enter key is not triggering by above code, please help me on it

Comment: Do you want to search after pressing enter key or you want to trigger enter event programatically?

Comment: I want to trigger enter event programmatically.

Comment: Are you getting any error in console? Or no error but event is not triggering? Please check if you are selecting your input textbox correctly using jQuery selector.

Comment: could you show html of your input?

Comment: Hi @Raf, below is the html of input: <input id="inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2_lsinput" title="Type something and hit enter to search this library" class="ms-helperText ms-textSmall ms-InlineSearch-SearchBox-Baseline ms-InlineSearch-SearchBox-EmptyUnfocused" type="text" value="" maxlength="2048">

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('<text-input-selector>').trigger(
    jQuery.Event('keypress', { keyCode: 13 })
);
```

Replace `<text-input-selector>` with appropriate jQuery selector for your input field.

If you are not able to get the correct selector then let me know and share the screenshot of textbox element by inspecting it. I will help you with jQuery selector.

**Update from Comments**:

Check below code. I have tested this and working fine for me:

```
//Set textbox value
$("input[title^='Search this site']").val(".pdf");

//Trigger Enter event on textbox
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 13;
e.keyCode = 13;

$("input[title^='Search this site']").trigger(e);
```

Comment: Sorry Ganesh, this is not working.

Comment: Check my updated answer. I have tried it on my SharePoint site and working fine for me. Use appropriate jQuery selector for your input textbox

Comment: Hi Ganesh, Have you tried on Library search? I have used below code, but no success

//Set textbox value
jQuery("input[title^='Type something and hit enter to search this library']").val(".pdf");
//Trigger Enter event on textbox
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");e.which = 13;e.keyCode = 13;

jQuery("input[title^='Type something and hit enter to search this library']").trigger(e);

Comment: Do you have jQuery file loaded on the page where you are executing this code (You will require jQuery to execute above code)? Are you getting any error in browser's console? Are you able to access the input element using the jQuery selector you mentioned in your code?

Comment: I am executing this code in console of browser and not getting any error in console.

Answer (score 0):

Try **keydown** event instead. Maybe it will work.

```
var e=jQuery.Event('keydown');
e.keyCode=13;                                 
jQuery('#inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2_lsinput').trigger(e);
```